# How to create "suitable await_ready function" for UWP C++/WinRT app?

Tags: c++, uwp, c++17, c++20, c++-winrt

I'm trying to create asynchronous event on user clicking a button in my XAMAL C++/WinRT UWP app. I've created Windows Runtime Component having a static IAsyncOperation function and I'm calling it with co_await which creates IntelliSense error:

> this co_await expression requires a suitable "await_ready" function and none was found'.

There are no build errors but exceptions like this are thrown on runtime:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC4EE3A839 in NOVATeacher.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_no_interface at memory location 0x000000A0332FCC60.

This is how I call the function:

```
IAsyncAction MainPage::ClickHandler(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
{
    co_await resume_background();

    auto login = co_await NOVAUtils::CurrentLoginAsync();
    myButton().Content(box_value(login));
}
```

This is how it's declared:

```
//NOVAUtils.idl
namespace NOVAShared
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass NOVAUtils
    {
        static Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<String> CurrentLoginAsync();
    }
}

//NOVAUtils.h
namespace winrt::NOVAShared::implementation
{
    struct NOVAUtils : NOVAUtilsT<NOVAUtils>
    {
        NOVAUtils() = delete;

        static winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<hstring> CurrentLoginAsync();
    };
}

//NOVAUtils.cpp
namespace winrt::NOVAShared::implementation
{
    IAsyncOperation<hstring> NOVAUtils::CurrentLoginAsync()
    {
        co_await resume_background();

        static hstring login = []()
        {
            auto users = User::FindAllAsync().get();

            hstring out;
            for_each(begin(users), end(users), [&](User user)
            {
                    hstring dname = unbox_value<hstring>(user.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties::DisplayName()));
                    out = out + dname + L", ";
            });

            return out;
        }();

        co_return login;
    }
}
```

The insides of CurrentLoginAsync() are obviously wrong and will give me all the logins and not the current login but that's just for testing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this line

```
hstring dname = unbox_value<hstring>(user.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties::DisplayName()))
```

The result of `user.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties::DisplayName())` is **IAsyncOperation<*IInspectable*>**, we could not convert it to **hstring** directly. For your requirement, you could append `.get()`behind the `GetPropertyAsync` method just like the following.

```
user.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties::DisplayName()).get().
```

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC4EE3A839 in NOVATeacher.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_no_interface at memory location 0x000000A0332FCC60.

The build error "**winrt::hresult_no_interface**" may be caused by above mis-used ,it can not convert **IAsuncOperation<*IInspectable*>** to **hstring**.

Comment: Since the code in question is in a coroutine itself, it's better to use the `co_await` operator rather than introducing a blocking wait by invoking `get()`, i.e. `co_await user.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties::DisplayName())`.

Comment: Answer worked but I've used for_each(begin, end, [&](T user)->IAsyncAction { co_await ... } so thanks for the tip @IInspectable - I didn't know I can do that.

Comment: @sms: That in itself doesn't buy you much. But if you also replace the other `get()` call with a non-blocking wait (`auto users{ co_await User::FindAllAsync() };`), you can drop the `resume_background` altogether. That's the more conventional way of implementing coroutines. Manually switching to a background thread should be reserved for cases, when you are calling into API's that do not provide an asynchronous interface.

Comment: @IInspectable what is the difference between "auto users = co_await FindAll()" and "auto users { co_await FindAll() }"? I don't have any get()s anymore. What if I have some heavy lifting withing the function itself (and not just calling some async methods) - do I use resume_background() then? Thenk you for being so helpful again and again here.

Comment: @sms: `auto x = ...` and `auto x{ ... }` are semantically identical in this case. The latter is using the uniform initialization syntax, introduced in C++11. If you do perform operations for an extended period of time, you should absolutely move it onto a worker thread by `co_await`ing `resume_background()`. The Windows Runtime has a threshold of 10ms. Anything that potentially runs longer is exposed as an asynchronous interface.